# How to check significance for non-mutually-exclusive classes (references welcome)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, references

**Setting**

There is a dataset in which every datapoint is a list of labels.  While I don't have direct access to the whole of the dataset nor to the whole list of labels (I could probably arrange it, but it's *huge* and I'm hoping it's not necessary), I do have access to datapoints containing certain labels of my choice ($A, B$ etc.) and, in particular, to the number of such datapoints, let's call it $num(A), num(B)$ etc. Just for reference, the values of $num$ tipically vary from 1 to about 150.000. I can also access "intersection" datapoints containing certain sublists of labels, e.g. $num(A\text{ and }B)$: these values range from 0 (quite obviously) up to several thousands.

**My problem**

For a certain label $C$ I see a more evident association with $A$ than with $B$ -- in the sense that $num(C\text{ and }A)/num(A)$ is quite bigger than $num(C\text{ and }B)/num(B)$ -- and I'd like to check for statistical significance.

In absence of intersections I'd consider a chi-squared test, but the intersection $num(A\text{ and }B)$ is up to 10% of $num(A)$ (for the labels I'm working with, $num(B)\gg num(A)$ with a difference of up to 3-4 orders of magnitude).

**My question**

Is there any standard(ish) technique to deal with this kind of scenarios and/or any sources you recommend to learn about it? I know embarrassingly little about statistics but I have a quite solid mathematical background.

P.S. This is my first question on SE, so feel free to suggest any improvement (linguistic ones too, English is not my mother tongue).